# How to remove an element inside a grid cell in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have the following scenario (trying to implement a checker game):

I have declared a grid with 8 rows and 8 columns. In some of them I paint a few ellipses programmatically in the following way:

```
this.myGrid.Children.Add(coin);
```

At this point all the ellipses are painted OK.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to remove or put invisible a specific column. I have tried these lines of codes:

```
this.gridTablero.Children.RemoveAt(1);
this.gridTablero.Children[1].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

But those lines of code remove the rectangles of the Grid instead of the ellipse. I have try to see if I can access the ellipse inside the cell but not luck :-(

If anyone know how to do this, any help would be very appreciate.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the statement "I can't figure out how to remove or put invisible a specific column".   Do you want to hide the coins in the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Children` property  is unrelated to the Grid layout, this property is part of `Panel` class (base class for `Grid` class), it just contains the collection of children elements without any information about layout.

So in your example `this.gridTablero.Children.RemoveAt(1);` remove second (0-based indexes) child element from `Grid`. Setting `Collapsed` as you saw already just change the `Visibility` property of second element.

This is how you can remove all elements from second row:

```
void HideAllElementsOnRow(int rowIndex)
{
    // Start from end so we can remove elements and continue to enumerate collection
    for (int index = this.gridTablero.Children.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        // If current element located on rowIndex position - we will remove it.
        if (Grid.GetRow(this.gridTablero.Children[index]) == rowIndex)
        {
            this.gridTablero.Children.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```